# Jelastic - Wordpress Multi Region Error 500 when server stop

Tags: wordpress, jelastic

I just setup a Multi Region Wordpress Cluster on Jelastic from the marketplace. I have two environnement on two different region. My domain is pointing to a load balancer who is configured to send everything to server 1 and switch to the server 2 when server 1 crash/stop.

Everything works fine except when I shutdown server 1. The site is working but I can't access the admin (Error 500: Internal Server Error) and I figured that the problem appear also when I go to server 2 without the load balancer.

So I'm wondering if this is suppose to work like that ? Like the server 2 is only here to let the visitor have no downtime but you can't write anything in the database.

(I already tried to reinstall a similar environnement and I get the same issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, such behaviour is expectable. This is caused by configuration of HA distributed shared storage based on GlusterFS. The only server1(master cluster) is an entry point for the **writes** and distributes content to the server2. As you probably has noted the Mutli-region cluster is on Beta and we're working on its improvment. In near future we will issue an add-on which will do reassigning the master role from one cluster to any other - in your case to delegate master role from server1 to server2 with a single click.